# How to use "Previous Calendar Quarter" in soql query

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

I have a requirement where i need to filter data for previous calendar quarter. How can we use "Previous Calendar Quarter" in soql(Not using any custom coding).

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_QUARTER`

Full reference for these special <strike>constants</strike> literals is [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm). Or you can look at [SOQL date functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm).

Answer (score 0):

The n value should be a negative integer representing the number of quarters you want to go back.

```
SELECT Id, Name, ClosingDate FROM Opportunity WHERE ClosingDate = NEXT_N_QUARTERS:-1
```